# Proving strong plausability argument for manifold volume definition in Munkress problem 22.4

Tags: integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Problem 4 in section 22 of Analysis on Manifolds by Mukress offers a nice plausability argument for the given definition of volume of a submanifold in R^n. Looking around out there I have found other plausability arguments (in do Carmo, Courant...) and solutions for some other problems, but not even a clue for this one (is marked). The first proposed step seems to really different from other arguments. I can not imagine which the six points mentioned should look like, or some geometric intuition behind evaluating the coefficients of the Jacobian at those ponts. Any help?